# AutoMapper без учета регистра букв

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть два класс:

```
 public class UserDTO
 {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int DivisionId { get; set; }
 }

 public class User
  {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int DivisionID { get; set; }
 }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как в настройках AutoMapper задать **игнорировать регистр букв**, чтобы свойства DivisionID перевести в DivisionId.

Answer (score 3):

Игнорировать регистр - это поведение по-умолчанию для AutoMapper [примерно с 2013 года](http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/6127).

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();

    var user = new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), DivisionID = 1 };
    var map = Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(user);
    Console.WriteLine(map.DivisionId);
}
```

На консоль выведится 1, т.е. поле `DivisionID` смапится на `DivisionId`.

В вашем случае проблема решается обновлением до актуальной версии.